# How to display function starting, ending line and function body?

Tags: c++, regex, linux, bash, parsing

Suppose I have a dictionary and inside a few files.cpp in which some C++ function are defined.

Example: file.cpp

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

void display(int a){
    cout << a;}

int square(int a) {
    return a * a;
}
```

My question is made of two parts:

1. How would I print out starting and ending line for specific function?
2. How would I print out entire function body?

I want to write a bash script.

Let's say I want to search for function sum.

Desired output:

```
Function sum is defined between lines 1 and 3.
int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Progress so far:

```
grep -rin --include=\*.cpp -ri "sum" | cut -d: -f2
```

The above command prints starting line numbers for function **sum**, i.e. in my case line 1.

Comment: What have you tried? Where'd it go wrong?

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflection (yet).

Comment: Are you using Bash to write a script to read C++ files? Or do you want C++ code to read other C++ files? Or a C++ program to search itself during runtime?

Comment: All I can say is good luck.  Parsing C++ is hard and no regular expression is going to be able to do it.  There are a lot of things that look like functions that may or or may not be functions.  Best I can offer is use something like clang-ast to get all of the function or add some documentation to you code and the search through the documentation.

Comment: I wrote some regex expressions to get first line and ending line. So far I have achieved to get the starting line, but I can't get the last line. My idea is to get first line, last line and then use awk and set NR to first and last line.

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes, I am writing a Bash file to read C++ files.

Comment: You should make that clear in the question. Also, edit it to show what you have done, and what isn't working for you.

Comment: @David As already pointed out, C++ is not a regular language, and regular expressions are not the right tool for finding the `}` that closes a function definition.

Comment: Here's a random C++ file: https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/range/primitives.hpp. Good luck parsing it with regex.

Comment: As has already been said, this is doomed to failure using a regular expression. The C++ grammar is *context sensitive* and *not* regular. Anything short of a full-blown compiler front end is going to fail miserably at this.

Answer (score 4):

C++ is not something you can parse easily.
For example, this code:

```
int func(a::b<c>d);
```

You can't say if it's a declaration (of an instance `d` of a `b` templated class in namespace `a`) or an expression (if you're comparing `b` static member of class `a` with `c` and then the result of this comparison with `d`) without having parsed the header and declarations.

Now, let's split this in multiple lines:

```
int func(a::
   b<c>
   d, 
   e f);
```

What is the start line ?

Also:

```
int func(a::b<c, d> g, e<f>);
```

You'll see here that a regular expression searching for a comma will fail in the latter case, since you'll trigger `d` as an argument (or worse, `d >` as a type).
You can have multiple level of embedded template, so you'd need then back lookup in the regular expression to solve this.

In the end, you'll end up (re)writing the front end of a compiler and it's a very complex task.

So to answer your question, you can't do it in bash (IMHO).
If I were you, I'd use clang here and let it find and extract the function signatures for you and possible the start and end of line for the function. 
If, and I'm guessing it, your intend is to provide code completion, then here's an example of usage:

```
clang -fsyntax-only -Xclang -code-completion-macros -Xclang -code-completion-patterns -Xclang -code-completion-brief-comments -Xclang -code-completion-at=file:line:col <clang-build-options here> <file>
```